# What exactly is a delta class?

Tags: computability

We've been learning the arithmetical hierarchy, but unfortunately the parts of the textbook used actually did not include the formal definitions of a $\Delta$ class (we are being provided with parts of a pdf). I was wondering if anyone could provide one. Thank you.

Comment: $\Delta_n^0 = \Sigma_n^0 \cap \Pi_n^0$.

Comment: @Hayden As in a set that can be expressed as both $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$?

Comment: Yep, exactly ${}{}{}{}$